# d3.js: how to create "force-directed graph clusters"

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

I've been exploring the d3.js library, and especially the force directed graph creation. I perused the paper on it by Bostock et al, and noticed the precise type of graph I'm trying to create, basically a force directed graph with color coded regions surrounding groups of a feather.

It's the illustration on 3rd column, 2nd row, here, labelled "force-directed graph clusters":
http://vis.stanford.edu/papers/d3

the code here generates the basic graph:
http://mbostock.github.com/d3/ex/force.html

My question is: what is the code to dynamically generate the region polygons?

Answer (score 8):

You could try integrating the example hull code with the force nodes.

Hull:
http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4341699

Force Layout:
http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1021841

This is the answer I provided in the comments:

http://bl.ocks.org/donaldh/2920551

Comment: that, @donaldh, is definitely a push in the right directions... now only if i were a coder... i am a designer, could you suggest some more specific integration examples

Comment: I wanted to experiment with this myself so have hacked the force-multi-foci example to add a convex hull. [http://bl.ocks.org/2918073](http://bl.ocks.org/2918073). When I get a chance I will extend the example to create a path around each category of nodes.

Comment: Okay, here is v2 with a convex hull for each cluster of nodes. http://bl.ocks.org/2920551. bl.ocks.org seems to be down just now so here is the gist https://gist.github.com/2920551

Comment: Wow, Donald! That is PERFECT! amazing! awesome! THANK YOU!

Answer (score 4):

See the [force-cluster example](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/tree/master/examples/force/force-cluster.html) in D3's repository.

Comment: Thanks Mike. I looked at that... that one has expandable circles representing the clusters. Is the code available to render the actual dynamic polygons as shown in the illustration?

Comment: link is now a 404.  Could you fix it?

Comment: Here is a cluster force layout example

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to the code that creates the circular nodes in the graph:

```
   var node = svg.selectAll("circle.node")
       .data(json.nodes)
     .enter().append("circle")
       .attr("class", "node")
       .attr("r", 5)
       .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })
       .call(force.drag);
```