# D3 force layout: clustering of graph nodes

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

I am trying to build a D3 force-directed graph similar to the example [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045). However, I would like to build a force-directed graph where the nodes can be clustered together based on some attribute. I am aware of D3's [cluster layout](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Cluster-Layout) but this seems tailored to dendrograms and forms of hierarchical clustering—not my intended use. I believe I am asking a question similar to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10731008/d3-js-how-to-create-force-directed-graph-clusters). Unfortunately, the URLs in the answers to this question are broken. Can anyone provide an example D3 visual similar to what I am trying to do?

Comment: You can still find one of the examples [here](https://bitbucket.org/john2x/d3test/src/2ce4dd511244/d3/examples/force/force-cluster.html).

Comment: Here's another example: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1747543